# Finite number of conjugations of subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

If $H$ is a group of finite index in $G$, prove that there is only a finite number of distinct subgroups in $G$ of the form $aHa^{-1}$

**Remark:** I am realizing that this problem maybe a famous and already exists in this forum but here i am working with mappings and i would like to know am i working with them correctly? So please check out my solution.

**Proof:** Suppose that $i_G(H)=p$ and cosets are $\{H_1, H_2,\dots, H_p\}$.

For any $g\in G$ consider the mapping $\phi: gHg^{-1}\mapsto (gH,Hg^{-1})$. It's easy to check that $gHg^{-1}=gHHg^{-1}$. This mapping $\phi$ takes on at most $p^2$ values and we'll prove that $\phi$ is injective.
If $(g_1H,Hg_1^{-1})=(g_2H,Hg_2^{-1})$ then $g_1Hg_1^{-1}=g_1HHg_1^{-1}=g_2HHg_2^{-1}=g_2Hg_2^{-1}$. Since $\phi$ is injective then number of conjugations $gHg^{-1}$ is at most $p^2$.

Thus we have shown that there is a finite number of distinct subgroups of $G$ of the form $gHg^{-1}$.

Is my solution complete and correct?

Please do not downvote it (read remark)

Comment: Why is your mapping well-defined? I.e. why does $gHg^{-1} = g' H g'^{-1}$ imply $gH = g'H$ and $Hg^{-1} = Hg'^{-1}$?

Comment: Obviously the map is not well defined, i.e. consider $H$ normal.

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck, it is a good question. I guess that my mapping is not well-defined :(

Comment: @freakish, why this map is not well-defined?

Comment: @RFZ Consider $H$ normal. Then for any $g$ you have $gHg^{-1}=H$, i.e the domain has only one element. So you claim that for any $g$ we have $gH=H$ which is obviously false.

Comment: @freakish, Unfortunately i am not familiar with notion of normal group. This will be in the next chapter of my book

Comment: @RFZ Right, consider any abelian group $G$ and any subgroup $H$. Then $gHg^{-1}=H$. But if $g\not\in H$ then $gH\neq H$. But you claim $(H, H)=\phi(H)=\phi(gHg^{-1})=(gH, Hg)$.

Comment: @RFZ But you are very close. What you actually need is to take a mapping $gH\mapsto gHg^{-1}$ and show that it is onto. Unlike your idea, my mapping **is** well defined (which of course you should show), i.e. if $gH=kH$ then $gHg^{-1}=kHk^{-1}$ (the reverse implication, the one you wanted to use, is not true).

Comment: @freakish, Indeed nice example above! Let me ask you one question: How did you come up with above mapping?

Comment: @RFZ Hmm, don't know. Just playing around with your idea plus some experience I guess?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70042/discussion-between-rfz-and-freakish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is unfortunately not good. Your $\phi$ function is not well defined. For example if $G$ is abelian and $H$ is any proper subgroup then $gHg^{-1}=H$ for any $g\in G$. But if $g\not\in H$ then $gH\neq H$. However calculate your $\phi$:

$$(H,H)=\phi(H)=\phi(gHg^{-1})=(gH,Hg)$$

It's a contradiction. Hence $\phi$ is not good.

> **Lemma.** Let $G$ be a group, $H\subseteq G$ a subgroup and $g, k\in G$. If $gH=kH$ then $gHg^{-1}=kHk^{-1}$.

*Proof.* $gH=kH$ if and only if $k^{-1}gH=H$ and this is if and only if $k^{-1}g\in H$. Note that $g^{-1}k=(k^{-1}g)^{-1}\in H$ and thus $Hg^{-1}k=H$. Therefore

$$k^{-1}gHg^{-1}k=(k^{-1}gH)g^{-1}k=Hg^{-1}k=H$$

and thus

$$gHg^{-1}=kHk^{-1}$$

$\Box$

The problem with your function is that you wanted the reversed implication, which I've shown not to be true.

Now simply define

$$\phi:gH\mapsto gHg^{-1}$$

I already shown that $\phi$ is well defined (that's what the Lemma is for). It is "onto" almost by the definition. Therefore the image is finite since we assume that the domain is.

Comment: How to derive ontoness from definition of mapping?

Comment: @RFZ Quite easy, if you have a subgroup of the form $aHa^{-1}$ then $\phi(aH)=aHa^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for good answer!

Answer (score 3):

Hint (I know you try to do it differently, but this introduces a more conceptual approach that helps with other parts in group theory, like Sylow theory): you might choose another route: the number of conjugate subgroups is counted through $N_G(H)=\{g \in G: g^{-1}Hg=H\}$. This is a subgroup of $G$ called the *normalizer* of $H$ in $G$. Now, the number of conjugates of $H$ is exactly equal to $|G:N_G(H)|$ (try to prove that). Finally $H \subseteq N_G(H)$, hence $|G:N_G(H)| \leq |G:H|$.

**Proofs**
Define a function from the left cosets of $N_G(H)$ in $G$ to the conjugates of $H$ as follows: $f: \{gN_G(H):g \in G\} \rightarrow \{gHg^{-1}: g \in G\}$ by $f(gN_G(H))=gHg^{-1}$. We will show that (a) $f$ is well-defined (that is independent of the coset representative) and (b) that $f$ is bijective. Since the cardinality of the first set equals $|G:N_G(H)|$ we are then done. 
Assume that $g_1N_G(H)=g_2N_G(H)$, then $g_1^{-1}g_2 \in N_G(H)$ (*) and hence $g_2Hg_2^{-1}=  g_1 \cdot g_1^{-1}g_2Hg_2^{-1}= \text{(because of (*)) } g_1Hg_1^{-1}g_2g_2^{-1}=g_1Hg_1^{-1}$. So (a) holds. Surjectivity of $f$ is immediate. And if $g_1Hg_1^{-1}=g_2Hg_2^{-1}$, then $g_1^{-1}g_2 \in N_G(H)$, whence $g_1N_G(H)=g_2N_G(H)$ and $f$ is injective.

In general, if $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$, with $H \subseteq K \subseteq  G$, then $|G:H|=|G:K| \cdot |K:H|$. For a proof that uses transversals in connection to the definition of cosets and indices of a subgroup see $1.3.5$ in [D.J.S. Robinson, A Course in the Theory of Groups](https://ia800204.us.archive.org/16/items/springer_10.1007-978-1-4419-8594-1/10.1007-978-1-4419-8594-1.pdf).

Comment: Dear, Nicky! Firstly, i do not know how to prove that the number of conjugates of $H$ is equal to $|G:N_G(H)$? and also no idea how to prove the second inequality

Comment: First part hint: if $g_1^{-1}Hg_1=g_2^{-1}Hg_2$ if and only if $g_1g_2^{-1} \in N_G(H)$ if and only if $g_1 \in N_G(H)g_2$.

Comment: I am in the begining of group theory but even the first equality is difficult to me. Maybe I am able to prove that if $G$ is finite

Comment: Hmm, not sure how much group theory you have digested, let's start with the second inequality first: if you have a inclusion of subgroups, say $K \subseteq H \subseteq G$, where $|G:K|$ is finite, then for the indices one has $|G:H| \cdot |H:K|=|G:K|$.

Comment: It would be interesting to take a look at a whole proof of your statements?

Comment: OK, will add that later today, I do not have the time now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70052/discussion-between-nicky-hekster-and-rfz).

Comment: Please add. Will be waiting your proof.